# Query builder on hasMany relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**Problem**

I'm creating an API with Laravel. Every server can have more than one contact, and every contact belongs to one server - as such, contacts are set up with a `belongsTo` relationship, and servers have a `hasMany` relationship to the contacts.

A user can have many servers via its `hasMany` relationship. Thus, when creating a server, we simply invoke `$user->server()->create([values])`, which works just fine.

The issue is that when we try to invoke it further, as with contacts - we hit a wall where we get:

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::contacts()`

When using: `$user->server()->contacts()->create([])`.

The method *does* exist in the server model.
We also have a hasManyThrough relationship on the user model, specifying that a user has many contacts through servers.

When calling `$user->contact()->create([])`, we instead get:

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::create()`

Does anyone have a clue what might be causing this? Do query builders not allow for this type of chaining, or am I missing something blatantly obvious? As you can see, I've tried a few different methods but can't seem to produce a working result.

Cheers!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't create through `hasManyThrough`. The example that Laravel gives for this relationship of "post" and "country" through "user". A Post can belong to a Country if its User is a part of that country. Through that logic, you're trying to create a country from a post. Doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Jaw.sh That makes sense - but why won't it work through the HasMany?

Comment: I don't know. The Laravel 5.2 API says that the `HasMany` relationship has a `create()` function. Something else is wrong. https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.html#method_create

Comment: (But, as expected, `HasManyThrough` does not.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said:

> A user can have many servers via its hasMany relationship.

so You cannot build another relation on relation that can return many results (becasue at the end we don't know exacly which server id we should set in contact new record).

So what you can do is to itterate over:

```
foreach ($user->server as $server) {
    $server->contacts()->create($values);
}
```

You see: now you have specific server with id to put into new contact record.

Comment: You are of course correct! I went the route of: `$srv = $user->server()->find($server_id)` and then created the contact via `$srv->contacts()->create([])` which immediately worked. Cheers!